Changing autocomplete Shortcut Key in VS2022
How to modify the autocomplete shortcut key for VS2022? It defaults to the Tab or Enter key, but I want to change it to something else. I tried searching for "Comp" in Options ->Environment ->Text Editor, but the default shortcut keys for the listed functions did not display "Tab" or "Enter".

Have you read the documentation on how to use stackoverflow? This is a question about a tool (visual studio 2022) not about C++, not about visual studio code (so I removed those tags). And "how do I do something ?" questions are out-of-scope here.

After my testing, you can achieve a similar effect as you want by: Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Show commands containing: Edit.InsertTab. Then press the new shortcut keys you wish to use in the "Press shortcut keys" box. Click the Assign button to assign the new shortcut keys.
